# X-Ray data of AGN

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, x-rays, satellites, quasars

I have downloaded spectra of a quasar from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS), but it has data in Visible Range. I need data of same quasar in the X-Ray region and I think SDSS don't have data in the X-Ray region. So where should I search for the data? Can I get the X-Ray data from the XMM Newton?

Answer (score 0):

ESA missions have a legacy archive on the ESA website.
For XMM Newton see https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/xmm-newton/xsa

Usually, these databases are open, at least after a proprietary period.

However, I must say, that the data on those archives can be pretty difficult to understand, so you better look for some high-level catalogs, which contain only the cleaned data.